# Mongodb $expr on array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Mongodb: 4.0.13

I'm having troubles in understand and get working $expr with arrays.

Let' start and create a new collection (dbRepeatElement) with following document:

```
db.testRepeatElement.insert([
{
    "data" : {
        "FlsResSemires_2" : {
            "Sospensione" : [
                {
                    "DataInizio" : 1548806400000,
                    "DataFine" : 1549065600000,
                    "Motivazione" : "1"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "derived" : {
        "DATAFINEANNORIFERIMENTO" : 1609372800000,
        "regione190" : "190",
        "REGAOEROG" : "190209820300",
        "REGASLEROG" : "190209"
    }
}    
])
```

In a bigger aggregation, following part is not working:

```
db.testRepeatElement.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
             $expr: {
                 $gt: ["$data.FlsResSemires_2.Sospensione.DataInizio", "$derived.DATAFINEANNORIFERIMENTO"]
             }
        }
    }

])
```

**Result**: return a match ( wrong! just check dates)

Reading mongodb documentation seems to be, using combination with arrays, aggregation and $expr does not return expected result and you have to specify with element of the array you want to check, like:

```
db.testRepeatElement.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
             $expr: {
                 $gt: ["$data.FlsResSemires_2.0.Sospensione.DataInizio", "$derived.DATAFINEANNORIFERIMENTO"]
             }
        }
    }

])
```

**Result**: return no match (right!)

**Question**: my requirement is to check every element in the array, so how to solve this, without using $unwind? Why there is this kind of result ?

Comment: You have to use [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/index.html) within the `$project` (or `addFileds`) stage.

Comment: could you provide a complete answer ? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$filter` aggregation operator is used to do the *match* operation on array elements. The following aggregation query will result only the `Sospensione` array elements which match the `$gt` condition:

```
db.testRepeatElement.aggregate( [
{
  $addFields: {
      "data.FlsResSemires_2.Sospensione": {
          $filter: {
              input: "$data.FlsResSemires_2.Sospensione",
              cond: {
                $gt: [ "$$this.DataInizio", "$derived.DATAFINEANNORIFERIMENTO" ]
              }
          }
      }
  }
},
{
   $match: { 
       $expr: {
            $gt: [ { $size: "$data.FlsResSemires_2.Sospensione" }, 0 ]
       }
   }
}
] ).pretty()
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to intepret result, I have:
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5e5d05c435fcda1954b46ea3"),
 "data" : {
  "FlsResSemires_2" : {
   "Sospensione" : [ ]
  }
 },
 "derived" : {
  "DATAFINEANNORIFERIMENTO" : 1609372800000,
  "regione190" : "190",
  "REGAOEROG" : "190209820300",
  "REGASLEROG" : "190209"
 }
}

What does mean Sospensione : [] ?

Comment: _What does mean Sospensione : [] ?_: It means that the condition specified in the `cond` did not match for any of the `Sospensione` array elements.

Comment: okay fine, so I have to filter using a match all documents with empty array, because they don't match main condition. Thanks! Btw: I'm really surprised mongodb does not have a native way to do that and require extra steps..

Comment: I was just doing this a few minutes back, see similar filter on the empty array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487519/query-mongodb-aggregate-join-two-collections/60489889#60489889

Comment: _so I have to filter using a match all documents with empty array..._: I added the code for that. It removes documents with empty arrays from the output.